# php: split string into array by letters as delimiters

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

How to split `$str` into parts where any latin letter is a delimiter?

```
$str = "     Hello! How are you? How are you   doing?  ";
```

should return an array of

```
$arr  = ("     ", "! ", " ", " ", "? ", " ", " ", "   ", "?  ");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex. Splits on 1 or more `+` characters `a-z` or `A-Z`:

```
$arr = preg_split('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $str);
```

Add anything you want in the character class `[]` such as `0-9` for numbers or `'` for apostrophe etc...